# Configure multiple widgets at once by tag

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I'm looking for a way to configure multiple widgets at once that have the same tag. My current solution is to use a for loop and configure each one, but I feel like there has to be a better way. Ideally, I would like something like this:

```
root = Tk()
entry1 = Entry(root)
entry2 = Entry(root)
entry1.pack()
entry2.pack()
entry1.bindtags(entry1.bindtags() + ("entries",)) # Is there a better way to do this?
entry2.bindtags(entry2.bindtags() + ("entries",))
root.class_configure("entries", state=DISABLED) # Pseudo code
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way in tkinter to modify multiple widgets at once. You gave an example using bindtags, but that's not what bindtags are for.

That being said, you can write helper functions that loop over widgets, and you can group widgets using lists or dictionaries. Or, you could certainly loop over all widgets, and only perform certain actions on widgets with certain bindtags.

In the simplest case it might look something like this:

```
entry1 = Entry(...)
entry2 = Entry(...)
entries = (entry1, entry2)
...
def disable_all_entries():
    for entry in entries:
        entry.configure(state="disabled")
```